# Best way to find desktop idle time of a user in electron based desktop app

Tags: electron, desktop-application, desktop

I want to know what are the best options when I want to find out desktop idle time through a desktop app made using electronjs.

Comment: Idle time in the meaning of low CPU-Consumption, or in the meaning of no user interaction?

Comment: @Torf meaning no user interaction. No mouse movement or keyboard key press.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to find the idle time *outside* your Electron Application:

This is not possible. Listening to mouse movements, clicks that are happening somewhere on your screen while your electron application is not focused or minimized is outside the scope of electron. At least when you work in electron directly.

Of course you could write a small C++ program that monitors those event direct in the operating system and reports to electron. But that would be quite a task.

Comment: This applies for electron desktop app? Seems like this is specific to mouse movement or key press inside the webpage where the js will load.. am I right?

Comment: I use exactly this code in an electron Desktop app. Electron is a Chromium browser with a bundled Node.js backend. So all your mouse movements and clicks will be inside a browser as your Electron app is in fact a browser with a webpage.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. This code will work when we want to know when user is idle on desktop app itself. 

But I want to know when user is idle on desktop and not just on desktop app. Above code will fails, when I minimize the desktop app but continue working on the any other app.

Comment: Oh. I see. That was not clear from the Question. So I'll edit my Answer.

Comment: Saw your edited answer now. I understand that it might not be possible. 
There is a powerMonitor API available in electrong which according to documentation might make it possible but I am unable to get it to work. 

Is it possible for you to try it once in your app ?

Comment: Not sure if that does what you  are looking for, but it's worth a try. But I have never tried to use it in that way, and do not have the time to implement it at the moment. Also https://github.com/anaisbetts/node-system-idle-time seems to monitor system idle time.